# Image is not displaying even with correct src?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason, my images just don't show up. Ive tried some css to force certain sizes but it has no effect. I have confirmed that imgs are being added to by div and have a valid src.

Some guidence would be great. Thank you.

Here is my JavaScript file:
,?

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="get()">Click me</button>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample JSON response

```
 {
    "albumId": 2,
    "id": 51,
    "title": "non sunt voluptatem placeat consequuntur rem incidunt",
    "url": "https://via.test.com/600/8e973b",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.test.com/150/8e973b"
 }
```

Comment: I can’t see your JS file contents.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need to create an `img` tag and not an `image` tag
`document.createElement('img');`

Also you can directly loop over an array you don't need to do `Object.keys` and then loop. This is how I would write the script.

```
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/2/photos';
function getImages() {
  fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', item.url);
        document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(img);
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an image element should be with `img` tag.

```
document.createElement('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

The element you're trying to create is `img` not an `image`.

Comment: I don’t understand why people put an answer that’s already here.

Comment: maybe because no answers were given when they saw the question, and they were typing the answer. Do you refresh the page whilst answer a question? I think not.

Edit: besides both of our answers could have been a "comment" to the question.

Answer (score -1):

`image` is not a tag in HTML, instead use `img`.

```
document.createElement('img');
```

Updated javascript code : (`Object.keys()` is not required since data is already an array)

```
const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/2/photos";
function getImages() {
  fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        data.forEach( obj => {
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute("src", obj.url);
            document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(img);
        })
    })
```

}